# Targets of Fighter plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If fighter plane travels along the path

> $$r(t)=(t-t^3,12-t^2,3-t),$$

how can we show that the pilot cannot hit any target on the x-axis? Any pointers and hints would be appreciated. I do not want full answer but a start because I am stuck in terms of how to approach this problem.

Comment: The path r(t) = what?

Comment: How can we now which targets the pilot can hit?

Comment: Your question needs to be fleshed out a bit. Can the plane only hit targets along the path you described via your function? You stated in your problem that the plan travels along that path, but most fighter planes can hit objects that are off in the distance.

Comment: Usually planes hit targets ahead of them and the pilot can hit a target on the x-axis only if they face it. But it is clear that does not happen if they move on the given path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably supposed to assume that the pilot can only shoot along the instantaneous direction of travel.  The question is then whether the tangent ray from the trajectory ever intersects the $x$ axis.  We have $r(t)=(t-t^3,12-t^2,3-t)$, so $r'(t)=(1-t^2,-2t,-1)$  Then we need to argue that $(t-t^3,12-t^2,3-t)+u(1-t^2,-2t,-1)$ never hits $y=z=0$ for any value of $t,u$ with $u \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

The fighter plane crosses the x-axis when y = 0 and z = 0 simultaneously. But when y = 0, $t^2 = 12$, and when z = 0, $t = 3$. There is no simultaneous solution to these two equations in $t$, so the plane never crosses the x-axis.